# FFMPEG sometimes adding black frames to the end of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm running some videos through ffmpeg to generate mp4, webm and ogg files for HTML5 player playback.

The videos are intended to loop, but sometimes ffmpeg adds black frames to the end - causing a flicker when looping.

I'm changing the frame rate to 24fps as part of the conversion - my guess is the problem lies somewhere therein.

My bash script (the important parts):

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 = input file
# $2 = output file name
# $3 = bitrate (in k)

# Variables
BITRATE=${3-1000}
BUFSIZE=$(($BITRATE * 2))
OGGBITRATE=$(($BITRATE * 100 / 85))
OGGBUFSIZE=$(($OGGBITRATE * 2))

echo "1. mp4 @ 720p - first pass"
ffmpeg \
-i $1 \
-vf scale=-1:720 \
-y \
-r 24 \
-an \
-vcodec h264 \
-preset veryslow \
-b:v "$BITRATE"k \
-maxrate "$BITRATE"k \
-bufsize "$BUFSIZE"k \
-pass 1 \
-f mp4 /dev/null

echo "1. mp4 @ 720p - second pass"
ffmpeg \
-i $1 \
-vf scale=-1:720 \
-y \
-r 24 \
-an \
-vcodec h264 \
-preset veryslow \
-b:v "$BITRATE"k \
-maxrate "$BITRATE"k \
-bufsize "$BUFSIZE"k \
-pass 2 \
-f mp4 \
"$DIST"/files/"$2".mp4[/code]
```

Example output

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 ' --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'animal-montage.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
  Duration: 00:00:33.65, start: 0.027520, bitrate: 7968 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7630 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
[swscaler @ 0x7f8a0c800600] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '[path redacted]':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A    
video:138kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Creating comp directory
Encoding dist files
1. mp4 @ 720p - first pass
ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 ' --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'animal-montage.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
  Duration: 00:00:33.65, start: 0.027520, bitrate: 7968 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7630 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] profile Main, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] 264 - core 144 r2533 c8a773e - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - [link removed] - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0 me=dia subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=5 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=1000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1000 vbv_bufsize=2000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, pass 1, 1000 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Past duration 0.639992 too large
Past duration 0.679985 too large
Past duration 0.719994 too large
Past duration 0.759987 too large
Past duration 0.799995 too large
Past duration 0.839989 too large
Past duration 0.879997 too large
Past duration 0.919991 too large
Past duration 0.959999 too large
frame=   68 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   72 fps= 41 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 droframe=   88 fps= 39 q=42.0 size=      54kB time=00:00:00.45 bitrate= 965.0kbits/frame=  106 fps= 37 q=40.0 size=     122kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate= 826.4kbits/frame=  124 fps= 37 q=39.0 size=     190kB time=00:00:01.95 bitrate= 795.9kbits/frame=  140 fps= 36 q=40.0 size=     270kB time=00:00:02.62 bitrate= 842.0kbits/frame=  157 fps= 36 q=40.0 size=     354kB time=00:00:03.33 bitrate= 870.2kbits/frame=  176 fps= 36 q=38.0 size=     436kB time=00:00:04.12 bitrate= 864.9kbits/frame=  193 fps= 35 q=39.0 size=     521kB time=00:00:04.83 bitrate= 882.2kbits/frame=  211 fps= 35 q=39.0 size=     650kB time=00:00:05.58 bitrate= 954.0kbits/frame=  228 fps= 35 q=39.0 size=     720kB time=00:00:06.29 bitrate= 937.1kbits/frame=  246 fps= 35 q=39.0 size=     813kB time=00:00:07.04 bitrate= 945.6kbits/frame=  262 fps= 34 q=41.0 size=     910kB time=00:00:07.70 bitrate= 966.8kbits/frame=  278 fps= 34 q=40.0 size=    1018kB time=00:00:08.37 bitrate= 996.0kbits/frame=  294 fps= 34 q=40.0 size=    1113kB time=00:00:09.04 bitrate=1008.3kbits/frame=  310 fps= 34 q=39.0 size=    1198kB time=00:00:09.70 bitrate=1011.1kbits/frame=  325 fps= 33 q=39.0 size=    1271kB time=00:00:10.33 bitrate=1007.4kbits/frame=  345 fps= 34 q=39.0 size=    1359kB time=00:00:11.16 bitrate= 996.8kbits/frame=  368 fps= 34 q=38.0 size=    1454kB time=00:00:12.12 bitrate= 982.1kbits/frame=  391 fps= 35 q=40.0 size=    1596kB time=00:00:13.08 bitrate= 999.6kbits/frame=  420 fps= 36 q=32.0 size=    1733kB time=00:00:14.29 bitrate= 993.2kbits/frame=  445 fps= 36 q=32.0 size=    1797kB time=00:00:15.33 bitrate= 960.2kbits/frame=  471 fps= 37 q=31.0 size=    1855kB time=00:00:16.41 bitrate= 925.6kbits/frame=  497 fps= 37 q=35.0 size=    2039kB time=00:00:17.50 bitrate= 954.4kbits/frame=  518 fps= 37 q=34.0 size=    2094kB time=00:00:18.37 bitrate= 933.4kbits/frame=  536 fps= 37 q=32.0 size=    2141kB time=00:00:19.12 bitrate= 917.3kbits/frame=  558 fps= 37 q=33.0 size=    2193kB time=00:00:20.04 bitrate= 896.2kbits/frame=  576 fps= 37 q=33.0 size=    2260kB time=00:00:20.79 bitrate= 890.4kbits/frame=  594 fps= 37 q=34.0 size=    2343kB time=00:00:21.54 bitrate= 890.9kbits/frame=  613 fps= 37 q=32.0 size=    2425kB time=00:00:22.33 bitrate= 889.6kbits/frame=  631 fps= 37 q=32.0 size=    2546kB time=00:00:23.08 bitrate= 903.7kbits/frame=  653 fps= 37 q=30.0 size=    2689kB time=00:00:24.00 bitrate= 917.8kbits/frame=  672 fps= 37 q=30.0 size=    2724kB time=00:00:24.79 bitrate= 900.0kbits/frame=  695 fps= 37 q=31.0 size=    2778kB time=00:00:25.75 bitrate= 883.8kbits/frame=  719 fps= 37 q=30.0 size=    2851kB time=00:00:26.75 bitrate= 873.2kbits/frame=  738 fps= 37 q=31.0 size=    2912kB time=00:00:27.54 bitrate= 866.3kbits/frame=  757 fps= 37 q=31.0 size=    2964kB time=00:00:28.33 bitrate= 857.1kbits/frame=  777 fps= 37 q=28.0 size=    3012kB time=00:00:29.16 bitrate= 846.0kbits/frame=  798 fps= 37 q=32.0 size=    3151kB time=00:00:30.04 bitrate= 859.2kbits/frame=  811 fps= 36 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3584kB time=00:00:33.70 bitrate= 871.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=32    
video:3576kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.235671%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] frame I:7     Avg QP:28.01  size: 75486
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] frame P:368   Avg QP:34.56  size:  7390
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] frame B:436   Avg QP:34.89  size:   948
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] consecutive B-frames: 24.7% 17.3% 12.2% 10.4% 12.9% 20.0%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] mb I  I16..4: 24.8%  0.0% 75.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] mb P  I16..4:  6.2%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 51.9%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:41.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  7.9%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 1.2%  skip:90.4%  L0:31.3% L1:56.7% BI:12.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] direct mvs  spatial:90.4% temporal:9.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.3% 36.9% 7.8% inter: 6.2% 3.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 31% 25% 33% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 18% 13% 10% 10%  7%  7%  7%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 69% 14% 14%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.3% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f878901ea00] kb/s:866.75
1. mp4 @ 720p - second pass
ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 ' --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'animal-montage.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
  Duration: 00:00:33.65, start: 0.027520, bitrate: 7968 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7630 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] profile High, level 5.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] x264 - core 144 r2533 c8a773e - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - [link removed] - options: cabac=1 ref=16 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=2pass mbtree=1 bitrate=1000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 cplxblur=20.0 qblur=0.5 vbv_maxrate=1000 vbv_bufsize=2000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '[path redacted]':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, pass 2, 1000 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 05:48:52
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Past duration 0.639992 too large
Past duration 0.679985 too large
Past duration 0.719994 too large
Past duration 0.759987 too large
Past duration 0.799995 too large
frame=   21 fps=0.0 q=39.0 size=      83kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=3262.1kbits/Past duration 0.839989 too large
Past duration 0.879997 too large
Past duration 0.919991 too large
Past duration 0.959999 too large
frame=   26 fps= 25 q=39.0 size=     111kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=2175.6kbits/frame=   29 fps= 18 q=39.0 size=     127kB time=00:00:00.54 bitrate=1919.3kbits/frame=   34 fps= 15 q=39.0 size=     157kB time=00:00:00.75 bitrate=1715.5kbits/frame=   39 fps= 14 q=40.0 size=     195kB time=00:00:00.95 bitrate=1664.5kbits/frame=   41 fps= 13 q=40.0 size=     202kB time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=1584.7kbits/frame=   46 fps= 12 q=40.0 size=     226kB time=00:00:01.25 bitrate=1482.2kbits/frame=   52 fps= 11 q=40.0 size=     245kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate=1337.3kbits/frame=   56 fps= 11 q=40.0 size=     263kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate=1291.2kbits/frame=   59 fps= 10 q=40.0 size=     272kB time=00:00:01.79 bitrate=1245.1kbits/frame=   64 fps= 10 q=40.0 size=     296kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=1211.1kbits/frame=   68 fps=9.2 q=40.0 size=     325kB time=00:00:02.16 bitrate=1227.8kbits/frame=   74 fps=8.9 q=40.0 size=     355kB time=00:00:02.41 bitrate=1202.1kbits/frame=   80 fps=8.8 q=40.0 size=     387kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=1189.6kbits/frame=   82 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     399kB time=00:00:02.75 bitrate=1188.0kbits/frame=   88 fps=8.4 q=40.0 size=     432kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=1178.8kbits/frame=   92 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     454kB time=00:00:03.16 bitrate=1175.3kbits/frame=   96 fps=8.2 q=40.0 size=     475kB time=00:00:03.33 bitrate=1167.7kbits/frame=  100 fps=8.2 q=40.0 size=     494kB time=00:00:03.50 bitrate=1155.8kbits/frame=  103 fps=8.1 q=40.0 size=     504kB time=00:00:03.62 bitrate=1139.5kbits/frame=  109 fps=8.0 q=40.0 size=     533kB time=00:00:03.87 bitrate=1126.0kbits/frame=  115 fps=8.1 q=40.0 size=     564kB time=00:00:04.12 bitrate=1120.8kbits/frame=  118 fps=8.0 q=40.0 size=     579kB time=00:00:04.25 bitrate=1116.9kbits/frame=  123 fps=7.9 q=40.0 size=     606kB time=00:00:04.45 bitrate=1112.6kbits/frame=  126 fps=7.9 q=40.0 size=     623kB time=00:00:04.58 bitrate=1112.9kbits/frame=  132 fps=7.9 q=40.0 size=     651kB time=00:00:04.83 bitrate=1102.6kbits/frame=  140 fps=8.1 q=40.0 size=     739kB time=00:00:05.16 bitrate=1171.2kbits/frame=  148 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     765kB time=00:00:05.50 bitrate=1138.7kbits/frame=  155 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     788kB time=00:00:05.79 bitrate=1114.1kbits/frame=  160 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     812kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=1108.2kbits/frame=  165 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     831kB time=00:00:06.20 bitrate=1097.1kbits/frame=  170 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     845kB time=00:00:06.41 bitrate=1078.7kbits/frame=  176 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     863kB time=00:00:06.66 bitrate=1060.1kbits/frame=  182 fps=8.3 q=40.0 size=     884kB time=00:00:06.91 bitrate=1046.8kbits/frame=  186 fps=8.0 q=40.0 size=     927kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=1072.3kbits/frame=  192 fps=8.0 q=40.0 size=     953kB time=00:00:07.33 bitrate=1064.4kbits/frame=  196 fps=8.0 q=40.0 size=     976kB time=00:00:07.50 bitrate=1065.8kbits/frame=  200 fps=8.0 q=40.0 size=    1000kB time=00:00:07.66 bitrate=1068.3kbits/frame=  204 fps=7.9 q=40.0 size=    1026kB time=00:00:07.83 bitrate=1072.7kbits/frame=  208 fps=7.9 q=40.0 size=    1050kB time=00:00:08.00 bitrate=1074.7kbits/frame=  212 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1080kB time=00:00:08.16 bitrate=1083.1kbits/frame=  217 fps=7.9 q=40.0 size=    1112kB time=00:00:08.37 bitrate=1087.5kbits/frame=  220 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1130kB time=00:00:08.50 bitrate=1088.8kbits/frame=  224 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1153kB time=00:00:08.66 bitrate=1089.8kbits/frame=  229 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1181kB time=00:00:08.87 bitrate=1090.0kbits/frame=  233 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1202kB time=00:00:09.04 bitrate=1089.1kbits/frame=  236 fps=7.7 q=40.0 size=    1221kB time=00:00:09.16 bitrate=1091.0kbits/frame=  242 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1252kB time=00:00:09.41 bitrate=1089.5kbits/frame=  248 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1283kB time=00:00:09.66 bitrate=1087.5kbits/frame=  254 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1312kB time=00:00:09.91 bitrate=1083.7kbits/frame=  260 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1342kB time=00:00:10.16 bitrate=1081.0kbits/frame=  266 fps=7.8 q=40.0 size=    1366kB time=00:00:10.41 bitrate=1074.6kbits/frame=  273 fps=7.6 q=40.0 size=    1405kB time=00:00:10.70 bitrate=1074.6kbits/frame=  279 fps=7.7 q=40.0 size=    1421kB time=00:00:10.95 bitrate=1062.3kbits/frame=  284 fps=7.7 q=40.0 size=    1443kB time=00:00:11.16 bitrate=1058.8kbits/frame=  289 fps=7.7 q=40.0 size=    1466kB time=00:00:11.37 bitrate=1055.8kbits/frame=  294 fps=7.7 q=40.0 size=    1488kB time=00:00:11.58 bitrate=1052.6kbits/frame=  299 fps=7.7 q=40.0 size=    1511kB time=00:00:11.79 bitrate=1049.9kbits/frame=  303 fps=7.6 q=40.0 size=    1532kB time=00:00:11.95 bitrate=1049.4kbits/frame=  309 fps=7.6 q=40.0 size=    1555kB time=00:00:12.20 bitrate=1043.4kbits/frame=  314 fps=7.6 q=40.0 size=    1579kB time=00:00:12.41 bitrate=1041.8kbits/frame=  315 fps=7.5 q=40.0 size=    1583kB time=00:00:12.45 bitrate=1040.6kbits/frame=  319 fps=7.5 q=40.0 size=    1602kB time=00:00:12.62 bitrate=1039.5kbits/frame=  321 fps=7.4 q=40.0 size=    1616kB time=00:00:12.70 bitrate=1041.4kbits/frame=  323 fps=7.4 q=40.0 size=    1633kB time=00:00:12.79 bitrate=1046.0kbits/frame=  327 fps=7.3 q=39.0 size=    1666kB time=00:00:12.95 bitrate=1053.0kbits/frame=  329 fps=7.3 q=38.0 size=    1687kB time=00:00:13.04 bitrate=1059.6kbits/frame=  344 fps=7.5 q=31.0 size=    1803kB time=00:00:13.66 bitrate=1080.6kbits/frame=  356 fps=7.6 q=32.0 size=    1844kB time=00:00:14.16 bitrate=1066.2kbits/frame=  364 fps=7.7 q=31.0 size=    1882kB time=00:00:14.50 bitrate=1063.1kbits/frame=  376 fps=7.8 q=33.0 size=    1919kB time=00:00:15.00 bitrate=1048.2kbits/frame=  385 fps=7.9 q=33.0 size=    1936kB time=00:00:15.37 bitrate=1031.7kbits/frame=  394 fps=8.0 q=31.0 size=    1968kB time=00:00:15.75 bitrate=1023.6kbits/frame=  400 fps=8.0 q=31.0 size=    1986kB time=00:00:16.00 bitrate=1016.8kbits/frame=  410 fps=8.2 q=31.0 size=    2002kB time=00:00:16.41 bitrate= 998.9kbits/frame=  422 fps=8.3 q=32.0 size=    2178kB time=00:00:16.91 bitrate=1054.6kbits/frame=  436 fps=8.4 q=33.0 size=    2245kB time=00:00:17.50 bitrate=1050.9kbits/frame=  444 fps=8.5 q=33.0 size=    2277kB time=00:00:17.83 bitrate=1046.0kbits/frame=  452 fps=8.5 q=33.0 size=    2318kB time=00:00:18.16 bitrate=1045.1kbits/frame=  462 fps=8.6 q=33.0 size=    2353kB time=00:00:18.58 bitrate=1037.5kbits/frame=  471 fps=8.7 q=32.0 size=    2386kB time=00:00:18.95 bitrate=1030.9kbits/frame=  476 fps=8.7 q=32.0 size=    2404kB time=00:00:19.16 bitrate=1027.5kbits/frame=  486 fps=8.7 q=32.0 size=    2434kB time=00:00:19.58 bitrate=1018.2kbits/frame=  495 fps=8.8 q=32.0 size=    2462kB time=00:00:19.95 bitrate=1010.5kbits/frame=  503 fps=8.9 q=32.0 size=    2471kB time=00:00:20.29 bitrate= 997.6kbits/frame=  514 fps=9.0 q=32.0 size=    2539kB time=00:00:20.75 bitrate=1002.2kbits/frame=  520 fps=9.0 q=32.0 size=    2574kB time=00:00:21.00 bitrate=1004.0kbits/frame=  526 fps=9.0 q=32.0 size=    2615kB time=00:00:21.25 bitrate=1008.0kbits/frame=  529 fps=9.0 q=33.0 size=    2634kB time=00:00:21.37 bitrate=1009.5kbits/frame=  534 fps=9.0 q=33.0 size=    2667kB time=00:00:21.58 bitrate=1012.1kbits/frame=  538 fps=8.9 q=33.0 size=    2698kB time=00:00:21.75 bitrate=1016.3kbits/frame=  541 fps=8.9 q=33.0 size=    2721kB time=00:00:21.87 bitrate=1019.0kbits/frame=  547 fps=8.8 q=33.0 size=    2746kB time=00:00:22.12 bitrate=1016.8kbits/frame=  553 fps=8.8 q=33.0 size=    2795kB time=00:00:22.37 bitrate=1023.2kbits/frame=  556 fps=8.8 q=33.0 size=    2822kB time=00:00:22.50 bitrate=1027.4kbits/frame=  560 fps=8.8 q=33.0 size=    2858kB time=00:00:22.66 bitrate=1032.9kbits/frame=  564 fps=8.8 q=34.0 size=    2894kB time=00:00:22.83 bitrate=1038.4kbits/frame=  567 fps=8.7 q=35.0 size=    2920kB time=00:00:22.95 bitrate=1041.8kbits/frame=  571 fps=8.7 q=33.0 size=    2949kB time=00:00:23.12 bitrate=1044.6kbits/frame=  575 fps=8.7 q=33.0 size=    2966kB time=00:00:23.29 bitrate=1043.3kbits/frame=  578 fps=8.7 q=36.0 size=    2979kB time=00:00:23.41 bitrate=1042.1kbits/frame=  593 fps=8.8 q=31.0 size=    3054kB time=00:00:24.04 bitrate=1040.7kbits/frame=  604 fps=8.9 q=29.0 size=    3082kB time=00:00:24.50 bitrate=1030.6kbits/frame=  616 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3114kB time=00:00:25.00 bitrate=1020.4kbits/frame=  622 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3131kB time=00:00:25.25 bitrate=1015.7kbits/frame=  628 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3149kB time=00:00:25.50 bitrate=1011.5kbits/frame=  634 fps=9.0 q=30.0 size=    3166kB time=00:00:25.75 bitrate=1007.3kbits/frame=  641 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3190kB time=00:00:26.04 bitrate=1003.4kbits/frame=  648 fps=9.0 q=30.0 size=    3229kB time=00:00:26.33 bitrate=1004.4kbits/frame=  652 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3253kB time=00:00:26.50 bitrate=1005.5kbits/frame=  658 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3278kB time=00:00:26.75 bitrate=1003.8kbits/frame=  663 fps=9.0 q=30.0 size=    3297kB time=00:00:26.95 bitrate=1001.8kbits/frame=  669 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3323kB time=00:00:27.20 bitrate=1000.4kbits/frame=  676 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3360kB time=00:00:27.50 bitrate=1000.9kbits/frame=  682 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3378kB time=00:00:27.75 bitrate= 997.1kbits/frame=  688 fps=9.1 q=29.0 size=    3402kB time=00:00:28.00 bitrate= 995.4kbits/frame=  695 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3450kB time=00:00:28.29 bitrate= 999.0kbits/frame=  700 fps=9.0 q=29.0 size=    3471kB time=00:00:28.50 bitrate= 997.7kbits/frame=  707 fps=9.1 q=29.0 size=    3492kB time=00:00:28.79 bitrate= 993.7kbits/frame=  716 fps=9.1 q=29.0 size=    3524kB time=00:00:29.16 bitrate= 989.7kbits/frame=  722 fps=9.1 q=29.0 size=    3538kB time=00:00:29.41 bitrate= 985.2kbits/frame=  731 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3618kB time=00:00:29.79 bitrate= 994.8kbits/frame=  740 fps=9.2 q=32.0 size=    3660kB time=00:00:30.16 bitrate= 993.9kbits/frame=  746 fps=9.2 q=32.0 size=    3702kB time=00:00:30.41 bitrate= 997.2kbits/frame=  752 fps=9.2 q=32.0 size=    3731kB time=00:00:30.66 bitrate= 996.5kbits/frame=  759 fps=9.2 q=32.0 size=    3766kB time=00:00:30.95 bitrate= 996.6kbits/frame=  765 fps=9.2 q=32.0 size=    3806kB time=00:00:31.20 bitrate= 999.0kbits/frame=  770 fps=9.2 q=32.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:31.41 bitrate=1001.2kbits/frame=  772 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3854kB time=00:00:31.50 bitrate=1002.3kbits/frame=  778 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3874kB time=00:00:31.75 bitrate= 999.5kbits/frame=  784 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3891kB time=00:00:32.00 bitrate= 996.1kbits/frame=  787 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3911kB time=00:00:32.12 bitrate= 997.3kbits/frame=  793 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3940kB time=00:00:32.37 bitrate= 996.9kbits/frame=  800 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3962kB time=00:00:32.66 bitrate= 993.6kbits/frame=  807 fps=9.1 q=32.0 size=    3988kB time=00:00:32.95 bitrate= 991.2kbits/frame=  811 fps=8.9 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4096kB time=00:00:33.70 bitrate= 995.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=32    
video:4088kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.206663%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] frame I:7     Avg QP:28.63  size: 73738
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] frame P:368   Avg QP:35.71  size:  8208
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] frame B:436   Avg QP:36.38  size:  1487
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] consecutive B-frames: 24.7% 17.3% 12.2% 10.4% 12.9% 20.0%  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] mb I  I16..4:  5.3% 71.1% 23.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  3.2%  0.1%  P16..4: 46.1%  5.0%  6.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:38.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 28.8%  1.2%  0.2%  direct: 0.4%  skip:69.3%  L0:34.1% L1:63.5% BI: 2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] 8x8 transform intra:76.8% inter:78.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] direct mvs  spatial:83.5% temporal:16.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 59.5% 45.7% 11.4% inter: 7.4% 4.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 24% 21% 30%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 11%  8% 13%  9% 12% 11% 12% 11% 13%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 11%  8% 11% 14% 10% 10% 10% 13%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 58% 19% 14%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.8% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] ref P L0: 68.3% 19.4%  6.4%  1.3%  1.1%  0.8%  0.7%  0.3%  0.3%  0.3%  0.2%  0.2%  0.2%  0.2%  0.2%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] ref B L0: 92.1%  3.9%  1.5%  0.6%  0.5%  0.4%  0.3%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] ref B L1: 96.1%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd98c801e00] kb/s:990.84
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your original videos don't contain a few black frames at the end ?

Comment: @Ely yes I think that was the issue. I couldn't see them on any video player but I used ffmpeg's black frame detector on my source and discovered that it does in fact end in a black frame.